# R Raster package: write NetCDF with time dimension

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, r, netcdf

I am writing a rasterbrick with multiple layers to a netcdf file using the raster package in R:

```
writeRaster(gridfile, "Data", "CDF", overwrite=TRUE,
     varname="Data",varunit="mm.d-1",longname="Monthly data",
     xname="lon",yname="lat", zname="time", zunit="month",bylayer=FALSE,NAflag=-9999)
```

Is there a way to have the data with time coordinates in the written ncdf file?
E.g. in the NetCDF Viewer Panoply I can plot the data in [lon][lat] but not in [time][lat].

Also how can specify the timesteps as specific months in a year instead of the timesteps starting from 1 and increasing?

Comment: I have found a solution using the ncdf package: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-January/017265.html However, is there a way to directly do this through the raster package?

Comment: Can you add some data, or at least include str(gridfile) and sessionInfo() so we know your R, raster, and ncdf/ncdf4 versions?

Comment: I wrote that answer and unfortunately I am still looking for a way to add time slices into netcdf files using the raster package.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone is still looking for an answer on how to do this in R the following code that will make a netCDF with 2 variables (prec, tmax), and 3 dimensions (long, lat, time). Pretty straight forward to change this suit your number of variables or time dimension etc.

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
prec <- getData("worldclim", res = 10, var = "prec")
tmax <- getData("worldclim", res = 10, var = "tmax")
tmax[] <- tmax[]/10 # tmax is scaled by 10
# Change NA values to -999
prec[is.na(prec)] <- tmax[is.na(tmax)] <- -999

# make sure the rasters are identical
compareRaster(prec, tmax, res = TRUE, orig = TRUE) ## TRUE

# output filename
filename <- "testMultiDim.nc"

# Longitude and Latitude data
xvals <- unique(values(init(prec, "x")))
yvals <- unique(values(init(prec, "y")))
nx <- length(xvals)
ny <- length(yvals)
lon <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees_east", xvals)
lat <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees_north", yvals)

# Missing value to use
mv <- -999

# Time component
time <- ncdim_def(name = "Time", 
                  units = "months", 
                  vals = 1:12, 
                  unlim = TRUE,
                  longname = "Month_of_year")

# Define the precipitation variables
var_prec <- ncvar_def(name = "precipitation",
                      units = "mm/month",
                      dim = list(lon, lat, time),
                      longname = "Monthly_Total_Precipitation",
                      missval = mv,
                      compression = 9)

# Define the temperature variables
var_temp <- ncvar_def(name = "temperature",
                      units = "degC",
                      dim = list(lon, lat, time),
                      longname = "Monthly_Avg_Temperature_degC",
                      missval = mv,
                      compression = 9)

# Add the variables to the file
ncout <- nc_create(filename, list(var_prec, var_temp), force_v4 = TRUE)
print(paste("The file has", ncout$nvars,"variables"))
print(paste("The file has", ncout$ndim,"dimensions"))

# add some global attributes
ncatt_put(ncout, 0, "Title", "MultiDimesionsalNCDFTest")
ncatt_put(ncout, 0, "Source", "Some example data from the raster package")
ncatt_put(ncout, 0, "References", "See the raster package")
ncatt_put(ncout, 0, "Created on", date())

# Place the precip and tmax values in the file
# need to loop through the layers to get them 
# to match to correct time index
for (i in 1:nlayers(prec)) { 
  #message("Processing layer ", i, " of ", nlayers(prec))
  ncvar_put(nc = ncout, 
            varid = var_prec, 
            vals = values(prec[[i]]), 
            start = c(1, 1, i), 
            count = c(-1, -1, 1))
  ncvar_put(ncout, var_temp, values(tmax[[i]]), 
            start = c(1, 1, i), 
            count = c(-1, -1, 1))
}
# Close the netcdf file when finished adding variables
nc_close(ncout)
```

You can open it and check the dimensions are correct

```
# Open the netcdf file
nc <- nc_open(filename)
nc
File testMultiDim.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     2 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float precipitation[longitude,latitude,Time]   (Chunking: [1080,450,1])  (Compression: level 9)
            units: mm/month
            _FillValue: -999
            long_name: Monthly_Total_Precipitation
        float temperature[longitude,latitude,Time]   (Chunking: [1080,450,1])  (Compression: level 9)
            units: degC
            _FillValue: -999
            long_name: Monthly_Avg_Temperature_degC

     3 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:2160
            units: degrees_east
            long_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:900
            units: degrees_north
            long_name: latitude
        Time  Size:12   *** is unlimited ***
            units: months
            long_name: Month_of_year

    4 global attributes:
        Title: MultiDimesionsalNCDFTest
        Source: Some example data from the raster package
        References: See the raster package
        Created on: Wed Nov 28 10:35:53 2018
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [R-Package netcdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf/index.html), it has much more possibilities to taylor your resulting data fields. To hold the GIS compatibility, use the Lon/Lat attribute schema beside the time attribute ([Spatial temporal advises](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html) ).

If you want to  create and use spatio temporal datasets like in climatology you should read the best practice article of [unidata.ucar.edu](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/BestPractices.html). There are several tools which work with netcdf spatio temporal standard structures.

[Mapping netcdf - NCL](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/)  | [NCO netCDF-Operator](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) | [CDO - Climate Data Operators](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo)

---

NCL Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Valid units strings for CF-compliant netcdf files look like "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00" or "days since 2013-04-19 00:00:00"

I think "months since ...." isn't supported by udunits since months are not equally sized.

You might do better thinking of the z dimension as a record dimension and then add a time variable with ncdf that locates each record in time.

Answer (score 0):

These days you can use

```
terra::writeCDF(x, "filename.nc")
```