# Displaying band names in netcdf file in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, netcdf

I have several netcdf files that contain multiple bands with useful names. When I import into R, the names are intact. However, when I import the netcdf files into ArcGIS 10.2 using the makeNETCDF raster layer tool, the names do not appear and I am left with "band1, band2" etc.

Does anyone know how to assign or import band names for netcdf files?